# Cannot write pandas DataFrame to csv: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tupleize_cols'

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, export-to-csv

I'm running the following basic code:

`dfMain.to_csv('./January_filtered_International_WE.csv')`

which used to run normally until yesterday. This morning I upgraded to `pandas 0.25.0` while running code and now I cannot write my 500k rows dataframe to a csv. I can mention that I left Jupyter Notebook running in order to do some processing, so this morning when I opened it I had the dataFrame already, processed.

Versions (using Windows 10)

```
Jupyter notebook : 5.7.8
Python : 3.6.7
Pandas : 0.25.0
```

I would like to save my DataFrame in a fast and efficient manner as I will load it  several times in the future. I do not want to close the notebook as this will delete the dataFrame.

I tried:

- downgrading to `Pandas 0.24.2` (previous version used) but still getting the `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tupleize_cols'`
- use `pd.to_pickle` but got a `memoryError`
- use `pd.to_hdf` but got a `memoryError`
- using msgbox instead but apparently it does not support DataFrames (got an error)
- upgrade Jupyter notebook, but got the following error:

`ERROR: ipython 5.8.0 has requirement prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4, but
you'll have prompt-toolkit 2.0.9 which is incompatible`

- so naturally I did pip install prompt-toolkit 1.0.16 but then got this message:

`ERROR: jupyter-console 6.0.0 has requirement prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0, but you'll have prompt-toolkit 1.0.16 which is incompatible.`

As an alternative I went into PyCharm and took a random `DataFrame.to_csv` and it worked. This makes me think the issue is with Jupyter Notebook.

Any help on how to save the DataFrame (~12 GB) is appreciated!

Comment: I think you should file that as a possible bug. But maybe you can check if maybe you use an incompatible version.

Comment: From this url you can create a new bug ticket: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27248

Comment: Thanks! Reinstalling Jupyter solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-installing Jupyter did the trick in my case

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting the same error, but updating Jupyter fixed it